# CSS nested selector not inheriting styling

Tags: html, css, sass, nested

I have the following nested styling:

```
ion-card {
  &.option-card {
    border-radius: 0.7rem;
    box-shadow: none;

    &-transparent {
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand it, any styling that comes before an inner nested selector should apply to that selector. But apparently it doesn't work that way. The desired outcome is that any element with the class `option-card-transparent` should have the properties `border-radius: 0.7rem` and `box-shadow: none`. Is this possible? Or should I use @extend?

I tried to move these properties outside, like below, and it did apply to all the nested selectors. Is this because it comes outside of nested class names?

```
ion-card {
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  box-shadow: none;
  &.option-card {

    &-transparent {
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just fire it in to a SASS to CSS converter and read the output https://jsonformatter.org/sass-to-css

Comment: Some CSS properties are inherited and some are not. For example, border-radius is not by default inherited. You can check on MDN site to see whether the property is inherited or not.  And you can use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS has been produced by SASS.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, What you are expecting is properties of parent to get inherited to child which is not the case, as using `&-` meaning you are creating a new class and not the child of that particular class

for example

```
.option-card {
    border-radius: 0.7rem;
    box-shadow: none;
   &-transparent {
    background: transparent;
   }
}
```

this will create

```
.option-card {
   border-radius: 0.7rem;
   box-shadow: none;
}

.option-card-transparent {
   background: transparent;
}
```

you need to specify which property you want to inherit from parent class

as for example,

```
.option-card {
    border-radius: 0.7rem;
    box-shadow: none;
   &-transparent {
    background: transparent;
     box-shadow: inherit;
     border-radius: inherit;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your rendering of the created CSS is quite right.

Comment: what part is not quite right ? that's scss getting converted to css i forgot to mention it @AHaworth

Comment: I think you've lost the nesting.

Comment: Oh yeah! that's correct i just gave him the example, it's not the same code that he mentioned.